# Geocoder API return only street addresses

Tags: javascript, google-geocoder

I am starting with Google's geocoder API and I want to only return a location_type of street_address.

The only problem it I don't know who to specifically request that. Here is my code right now:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'latLng':myLatLng}, function(results, status){
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        if(results.length > 0){
            console.log(results);
        }
        else{
            alert('nope');
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('nope');
    }
});
```

How do I specify that I only want of type street_address?

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentRestrictions` parameter and specify your `street_address` component like this:

```
geocoder.geocode({
   componentRestrictions:{
      street_address:'Avenue of The Stars',
   }
}, ... )
```

That way you are omitting the `address` param because you are querying a specific `street_address` component.

You can also combine one or any number of components and `address` parameter:

```
geocoder.geocode({
   address:'stars',
   componentRestrictions:{
      country:'United States',
      city:'Los Angeles',
   }
}, ... )
```

That way Geocode will search for ANY component type that includes string 'stars'.

You can find list of other queryable components here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types